# Ошибка при повторном вызове статического метода

Tags: java

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему возникает ошибка?

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Первый раз считывает. Во второй раз ошибка всплывает. Я так подозреваю, что это как-то связано с тем, что метод static. Но почему конкретно ошибка возникает понять не могу. Когда метод повторно вызывается поток создаётся повторно.

Если метод вызывается один раз - всё работает хорошо.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int x = readNumberFromConsole();
        int y = readNumberFromConsole();
    }

    private static int readNumberFromConsole() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reader.close()` закрывает все низлежащие потоки, включая `System.in`. Попытка чтения из закрытого потока вызывает исключение.